# In a permutation test, how to get a confidence interval for the estimated p-value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, nonparametric, permutation-test

Suppose that I have two groups of data of size $50$ and $51$. Assuming that I did an approximate Monte Carlo permutation test with 10,000 permutations randomly drawn, is there a way to find a confidence interval for the estimate of the $p$-value?

Suppose my estimate of the $p$-value is $0.0003$. What would I need to construct such a confidence interval?

Comment: "Confidence interval for a p-value" is a contradiction in terms.  Confidence intervals apply to *parameter estimates*, but a p-value most decidedly does not estimate any parameter. One proof of this is to observe that a p-value depends on sample size, whereas a parameter's value does not. Are you possibly asking for a confidence interval on the *Monte Carlo estimate* of a p-value?

Comment: hi, sorry, that is right, I am asking for the monte carlo estimate of a p-value

Comment: Your estimate $p=0.0003$ presumably means that you got 3 permutations out of 10000 yielding statistic at least as extreme as the empirically observed one. So you can ask for a [binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) given 3 out of 10000 successes. There are several methods to compute one (see wikipedia), in Matlab with `binofit(3,10000)` I get $(0.00006, 0.0009)$, this is I believe based on the Clopper-Pearson method.

Comment: Or repeat the permutation test, say, 10,000 times. Then compute order statistics for both tails (for a 95% interval, look at the 250th smallest and the 250th largest values) and there's your estimated interval.

Comment: @soakley, if you repeat permutation test with 10000 permutations 10000 times, you did 100 million permutations. Then you can directly estimate your p-value from these 100 million runs and get back to the same question about confidence interval as before. Also, 100 million permutations are rarely feasible.

Comment: @whuber I think there is a parameter (of sorts) here -- just not of the original problem (&one conditional on the observed values, as is the case with permutation tests). The parameter is the proportion of permuted samples that would be at least as extreme as the observed sample (as ordered by the test statistic and what is extreme can be identified by the alternative). With a randomization test, we're in a binomial sampling situation, where $n$ is the number of resamples taken and the parameter $p$ is the p-value we would have got if we'd found all the permutations rather than sampled them...

Comment: ctd ... and in that case I think one can talk about a standard error, and a confidence interval.

Comment: @Glen_b That is exactly the distinction I was suggesting.  But hasn't this question been asked and answered before on this site?

Comment: @whuber Oh, yes, I believe so.

Comment: @whuber Haven't found anything closer than your answer to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/not-sure-if-standard-error-of-p-values-makes-sense-in-fisher-exact-test) so far (which connection may not be immediately obvious to some readers). One of my own answers I located does talk about it a bit but not in enough detail. On the other hand I haven't had a lot of time to look. Do you have a suggested one?

Comment: @Glen_b No time to look now, but I recall seeing something almost exactly like this around two weeks ago.

Comment: Well anyway, here's some relevant Qs: [Q1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51304/confidence-interval-on-a-p-value), [Q2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/required-number-of-permutations-for-a-permutation-based-p-value), [Q3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/not-sure-if-standard-error-of-p-values-makes-sense-in-fisher-exact-test)