# Exactness of p-value in testing by simulation

Tags: p-value, simulation, precision

When I use simulation to determine a p-value I am aware that the exactness of my p-value will be at most an estimate because I am using the scores of my sample and not my population, so that my computed p is on average close to its true p-value.

*How do I deduce whether my estimate is a good estimate or a not-so-good estimate? Is there a some kind of rule?*

My guess would be that it should be something like N ≥ 30 but I would appreciate an official answer.

Comment: Answered on site many times. See for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223664/confidence-interval-for-the-p-value-estimate-when-doing-monte-carlo-testing or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/not-sure-if-standard-error-of-p-values-makes-sense-in-fisher-exact-test or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164424/permutation-test-for-f-statistics-in-the-ols-setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This effect is not limited to p values obtained by simulation. P values are a statistic, i.e., a function of the data you have observed (and your distributional assumptions and model). As such, they have an expectation and a variance. The variance is due to sampling variability.

Suppose you run an experiment, observe data and calculate a p value using some parametric approach. Now suppose you re-run the experiment in the *exact* same way, so the data generating process of both experiments is precisely identical. You will still get different p values, simply because of the variation in your experimental observations.

P values are a statistic. They have a variance.

Suggested reading: [Boos & Stefanski, "P-Value Precision and Reproducibility" (2011, *The American Statistician*)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tas.2011.10129). Also helpful: [The dance of the p values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL1RqHrZQ8).

> I am aware that the exactness of my p-value will be at most an estimate because I am using the scores of my sample and not my population

This is a misconception. If you measure your entire population, then you don't calculate p values any more, because then you know the true population parameter - there is no randomness involved any more. As above: the p value's variability comes from the sampling variability.

If you are running a simulation, then you are actually in luck, because then you can re-run your simulation a couple of times and see how the p values change. This can be very enlightening.

Incidentally, the variability of the p value is one of the reasons I am slightly exasperated by people treating any p value < .05 as the Holy Grail and any p value >= .05 as career threatening. (Which it may well be in some fields.)

There is no rule we could give you to say which $n$ is enough. It depends on your data variability, on your model, on your misspecification etc.

Comment: That's a great and helpful answer! Thanks also for the additional literature, I'm looking forward to reading it.